# having trouble creating a rounding program java using command lines

Tags: java, rounding

I'm fairly new to coding and I've been learning by creating simple programs.

I'm trying to create a program called roundGrade to round a grade to one decimal place by calling onto the command line.

The error stated:

```
Error: variable roundGrade might not have been initialized
```

Here's the code I've written so far:

```
public static String roundGrade(double grade){

    String roundGrade;
    double R = Double.parseDouble(roundGrade);
    R = Math.round(grade*10)/10;
    roundGrade = Double.toString(R);

    return roundGrade;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are attempting to parse `roundGrade` before you set it to anything (and for no apparent purpose). This

```
double R = Double.parseDouble(roundGrade);
R = Math.round(grade*10)/10;
```

should be something like

```
double R = Math.round(grade*10)/10;
```

And your entire method could be

```
return String.format("%.1f", grade);
```